# How to fix bcrypt crashing when deploying to aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i've built this node server, that i am trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (through a pipeline) using bcrypt as a dependency, but it doesn't seem to work well. here are the logs, for anyone intereted i can provide full last 100 lines.

```
2021/11/22 15:36:13.652664 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1 and node@14.17.1 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib' 
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("healthd") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.252-195.483.amzn2.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.17.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.17.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.17.1-linux-x64/bin/node /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.17.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
```

theese should be the key lines proving it's bcrypt's fault, but I can't understand how to fix it. Btw,it works locally, only crashes the aws.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this problem, just use bcryptjs instead of bcrypt, it's a bit slower, written in pure js, but pretty much should work just the same, except for the error. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) is it's npm page.